# How to configure a dynamic library using a macro / variable in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, dynamic-library

I'm writing a small study project in C. I need to create a dynamic library and configure its use with macros. First, I create object files with the command:

```
$gcc -fPIC -c ../data_module/data_process.c
$gcc -fPIC -c ../data_libs/data_stat.c
```

Then I create a dynamic library like this:

```
$gcc -shared -o data_process.so data_process.o data_stat.o
```

And finally I build an executable file using this library:

```
$gcc main_executable_module.o ../data_libs/data_io.o ../yet_another_decision_module/decision.o -L. data_process.so -o test_main
```

It works and the executable works correctly. But there is a task to configure the library using macros:

> Make the necessary changes to the code of the `main_executable_module`, configuring the use of the dynamic library using macros.

That is, if I understand correctly, you need to add macros to the `main_executable_module.o` so that you do not use the `-L` flags during assembly. But I can't find information anywhere on how to do it. Can you please tell me how to implement this or where can I read about it?

UPD:  John Bollinger says

> It is possible that the word "macros" is intended to be interpreted as makefile macros, which many people instead call (makefile) "variables". That would make this a question about make / makefiles, not about C.

My Makefile:

```
CC=gcc
LDFLAGS=
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -Wextra -Werror
SOURCES=main_executable_module.c ../data_libs/data_stat.c ../data_libs/data_io.c ../yet_another_decision_module/decision.c ../data_module/data_process.c
DYNLIB=../data_module/data_process.c
STAT=../data_libs/data_stat.c
BUILDDYN=main_executable_module.c ../data_libs/data_io.c ../yet_another_decision_module/decision.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
OBJBUILDDYN=$(BUILDDYN:.c=.o)
OBJDYNLIB=data_process.o
OBJDATASTAT=data_stat.o
EXECUTABLE=../../build/main
DEXECUTABLE=../../build/Quest_6
DLIBS=data_process.so

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

data_stat.a: $(OBJLIB) $(LIBS)
    ar -rcs $(LIBS) $(OBJLIB)

data_process.so: $(OBJDYNLIB) $(OBJDATASTAT)
    $(CC) -shared -o $(DLIBS) $(OBJDYNLIB) $(OBJDATASTAT)

$(OBJDYNLIB): $(DYNLIB)
    $(CC) -fPIC -c $(DYNLIB)

$(OBJDATASTAT): $(STAT)
    $(CC) -fPIC -c $(STAT)

build_with_dynamic:$(OBJECTS) $(EXECUTABLE)
    $(CC) $(OBJBUILDDYN) -L. $(DLIBS) -o $(DEXECUTABLE)


$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@


clean:
    rm -rf $(EXECUTABLE) $(OBJECTS)

lclean:
    rm -rf $(LEXECUTABLE) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) $(DEXECUTABLE)

rebuild: clean $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Comment: are you talking about C macros? or am I missing something?

Comment: @OznOg I need to configuring the use of the dynamic library using macros, to be honest, I myself do not fully understand what is meant

Comment: You need to ask the person who gave you the task. The task as you describe it is completely unclear. 1) You cannot replace a linker option on the command line with a C preprocessor macro. 2) You cannot change the compiled code of the library with a C preprocessor macro that is evaluated in the application using that library.

Comment: @thebusybee unfortunately there is no one to ask, because this task is not from a person
a direct quote from the assignment is this: Make the necessary changes to the code of the ```main_executable_module```, configuring the use of the dynamic library using macros.

Comment: Would you mind to provide a link, and optimally a [mre] of your solution? This assignment needs to have authors, did you try to contact them?

Comment: It is possible that the word "macros" is intended to be interpreted as *makefile* macros, which many people instead call (makefile) "variables".  That would make this a question about `make` / makefiles, not about C.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, that is right! This is a makefile task. These commands that I showed, I wrote down in the makefile, does this really mean that I used macros? (sorry for stupid questions)

Comment: @e7min, I see only commands, not makefile macros / variables, nor indeed anything else that looks like makefile content to me.  Perhaps you need to go back and review earlier parts of the course / tutorial you are trying to follow, because it sounds like you don't yet have a good foundation for the task you are asking about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger   I added a makefile that works and builds the result in Quest_6, there I use variables

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere.  The `CC`, `DLIBS`, *etc*. in that makefile are macros.  Some of those appearing in that makefile are involved in the rules for building and linking shared libraries and executables.  I am not sure whether those uses amount to what the authors of the exercise had in mind, but maybe so.

Comment: I'll write tomorrow after checking if I find out more

Answer (score 0):

The results of the checks revealed nothing. There are two opinions about this task.

1. Leave everything as above. And in the file itself, add a header `process.h`. Then everything is assembled and working. And at the same time, if you change the code in the library, rebuild it, and do not rebuild the executable file, then the changes will be taken into account. That is, the idea of ​​a dynamic library is respected.
2. Implement in such a way that there is no need to include headers in the `main_executable_module.c`. Then a special library is used for working with dynamic libraries, which allows you to write the path to the library and take individual functions from it. [More about it here](https://firststeps.ru/linux/r.php?8).

What was meant when it was said about macros, I still did not understand ...